# How to use itertools to output results of only a certain length

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

Suppose I have a list of bytes `(x00 to xFF)`. How can I use itertools to return only permutations that have length of X.
So for example I want all permutations with length 3, then I'll get

```
[x00,x00,x00], [x00,x00,x01], ..., [xFF,xFF,xFF]
```

That way there is no waste of computing resources.

EDIT: Doesn't have to be itertools if there is a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import itertools
for tup in itertools.product(range(0x100), repeat=3):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

[`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement):

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> import itertools
>>> 
>>> list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(my_list, 3))
[(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 4), 
 (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), 
 (1, 3, 3), (1, 3, 4), 
 (1, 4, 4), 
 (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 3), (2, 2, 4), 
 (2, 3, 3), (2, 3, 4), 
 (2, 4, 4), 
 (3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 4), 
 (3, 4, 4), 
 (4, 4, 4)]
```

---

Seems like you want all the permutations, with replacement. In that case, you need: [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) as in @gnibbler's answer.

Comment: Not sure if this is that the OP wants. You don't get [x00,x01,x00], [x01,x00,x00] etc. this way

Comment: @gnibbler. Yeah, now I got you. Since it was not specified in OP's output specifically, so I got it wrong firstly. :)

Comment: Yes, I want with repetition, just as @gnibbler stated

Answer (score 1):

It seems @gnibbler's solution is more correct?

```
In [162]: >>> l = [1, 2, 3]

In [163]: list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(l, 3))
Out[163]:
[(1, 1, 1),
 (1, 1, 2),
 (1, 1, 3),
 (1, 2, 2),
 (1, 2, 3),
 (1, 3, 3),
 (2, 2, 2),
 (2, 2, 3),
 (2, 3, 3),
 (3, 3, 3)]

In [164]: list(itertools.product(l, repeat=3))
Out[164]:
[(1, 1, 1),
 (1, 1, 2),
 (1, 1, 3),
 (1, 2, 1),
 (1, 2, 2),
 (1, 2, 3),
 (1, 3, 1),
 (1, 3, 2),
 (1, 3, 3),
 (2, 1, 1),
 (2, 1, 2),
 (2, 1, 3),
 (2, 2, 1),
 (2, 2, 2),
 (2, 2, 3),
 (2, 3, 1),
 (2, 3, 2),
 (2, 3, 3),
 (3, 1, 1),
 (3, 1, 2),
 (3, 1, 3),
 (3, 2, 1),
 (3, 2, 2),
 (3, 2, 3),
 (3, 3, 1),
 (3, 3, 2),
 (3, 3, 3)]
```